# Is there a way to change data frame entries in R from numeric to a specific character?

Tags: r

If I have a data frame like so:

```
df <- data.frame(
a = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3),
b = c(1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3)
)
```

which looks like this:

```
> df
  a b
  1 1
  1 2
  1 3
  2 1
  2 2
  2 3
  3 1
  3 2
  3 3
```

Is there a quick way to change the columns `a` and `b` to match the example below, without explicitly having to type it all out?

```
> df
   a  b
  a1 b1
  a1 b2
  a1 b3
  a2 b1
  a2 b2
  a2 b3
  a3 b1
  a3 b2
  a3 b3
```

In other words, Im trying to take the name of the column and just place it in front of the value that was in that row originally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `cur_column` to return the corresponding column name within `across` and `paste` (`str_c`) the column value with the corresponding column name

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df1 <- df %>% 
      mutate(across(everything(), ~ str_c(cur_column(), .)))
```

-output

```
df1
#   a  b
#1 a1 b1
#2 a1 b2
#3 a1 b3
#4 a2 b1
#5 a2 b2
#6 a2 b3
#7 a3 b1
#8 a3 b2
#9 a3 b3
```

---

Or using `base R`

```
df[] <- Map(paste0, names(df), df)
```

Or another option is

```
df[] <-  paste0(names(df)[col(df)], unlist(df))
```

Comment: excellent answers. Something I forgot though, what if my data frame has, say, three columns a,b, and y... and I just want to apply your method to columns a and b and leave y unchanged... is that possible?

Comment: @Electrino you can use `across(c(a, b), ~` in the first solution. In second `df[c('a', 'b')] <- Map(paste0, c('a', 'b'), df[c('a', 'b')])`

Comment: excellent. I was thinking something like : `df[,1:2] <-  paste0(names(df[1:2])[col(df[1:2])], unlist(df[,1:2]))` but your solutions are much clearer. Thanks